# What is the structure of this layout?

Tags: android

Is this a `TableLayout`? If it is, how to make this underline under first row and different color per row?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this is a `TableLayout`? I think it's pretty easy to create such form with `ListView`+`ListView` header, not with `TableLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is derived from a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) (object containing children, for example [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)), it is easy to access all of its children (rows) and do something with it. For example alternating backgrounds:

```
final int childCount = myGroup.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
  View child = myGroup.getChildAt(i);
  if(i % 2 == 0) {
    child.setBackgroundColor(color1);
  } else {
    child.setBackgroundColor(color2);
  }
}
```

Same goes for changing the first row, just use `myGroup.getChildAt(0)` and modify that particular child.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the table layout you have to set background color of the table row please refer for following link click [here](http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a Table layout

i have created the similar very easily.

You can also add click events for the text in each row to perform different action.

[image: check this]

Comment: Instead of showing that you did something, it would be nicer to show *how* you did it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use listview with custom item view. Just add header in listview (also footer can be added):

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, list, false);
list.addHeaderView(headerView);
```